# How to make String behave like Integer?

Tags: java, string, integer, ip, transform

I'm a newbie trying to learn Java. Currently making little programs to practice.

I'm trying to make a program that, given a IPV4 address, netmask and number of subnetworks required by the user, can output each subnet net ip, host ip range and broadcast ip.

The thing is, how can I transform the given IPV4 address by the user to behave like an Integer to add numbers to it and display it earlier?

For example:

Given IPV4 Address: 10.2.0.0/19
Required subnetworks: 40

The subnet 0 would start from 10.2.0.0 to 10.2.0.127.

How can i output transform 10.2.0.0 to 10.2.0.127? And from this last one to 10.2.0.255, that is the next subnet 1 ip range.

Until now, i've tried this:

```
        while(Subnet > scounter) {
        String finalip = IPV4Add.substring(0, IPV4Add.length() - 1) + (MagicNum - 1);
        System.out.println("Subnet " + scounter + " Net Address: " + IPV4Add + " to " + finalip);
        scounter++;
        }
```

Output(only 3 lines instead of 39):

```
Subnet 0 Net Address: 10.2.0.0 to 10.2.0.127
Subnet 1 Net Address: 10.2.0.0 to 10.2.0.127
Subnet 2 Net Address: 10.2.0.0 to 10.2.0.127
```

Where **Subnet** is the number of subnetworks required by the user, **scounter** to is to count the subnetworks outputted and **MagicNum** is the number which should be added to the ip to obtain the next subnetwork, in this example, 128.

How can i edit the String to make it behave like integer and give me, adding in each loop,:

```
Subnet 1 Net Address: 10.2.0.128 to 10.2.0.255 
Subnet 2 Net Address: 10.2.1.0 to 10.2.1.127
Subnet 3 Net Address: 10.2.1.128 to 10.2.1.255
```

And so on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, the split() method gave me ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to output a list of ranges with the difference between ranges equal to 128. One way to achieve this is to define a new addition method which looks at numbers as fields in the IP address.

The first step would be to split the IP address string and store it as an integer array containing four numbers.

```
String[] stringIPAddr = "10.2.0.0".split("\\.");
int[] ipAddr = new int[4];
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    ipAddr[j] = Integer.parseInt(stringIPAddr[j]);
}
```

The ranges in this problem are pretty well defined. They all start with 0 and end with 127. The next range starts with 128 and ends at 255. the following function takes care of jumping to the next value in range *in place*:

```
void nextAddr(int[] number) {
    if(number[3] == 0) number[3] = 127 ;
    else if(number[3] == 128) number[3] = 255;
}
```

After we print first and last value of the range, we want to increment it by one and go to the next range. Here we should also be careful to increment the number correctly if the last field is equal to 255. In this case, a carry propagates through the fields (just like regular addition/subtraction):

```
void increment (int[] number) {
    int carry = 1;
    for(int i = 3; i >=0; i--) {
        number[i] += carry;
        if(number[i] == 256) {
            carry = 1;
            number[i] = 0;
        } else carry = 0;
    }
}
```

This function increments the IP address by one in place. If a field becomes 256, the function sets the field to zero and propagates a carry to the next field in the summation operation. The idea is like regular addition with the modification that a carry goes to the previous field if the number becomes equal to 256.

Having nextAddr and increment methods, writing the main loop is easy:

```
for(int i = 0; i < subNetWorks; i++) {
        System.out.print("Subnet " + i + " Net Address:" +
                Arrays.toString(ipAddr) + " to ");
        nextAddr(ipAddr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ipAddr));
        increment(ipAddr);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Subnet 0 Net Address:[10, 2, 0, 0] to [10, 2, 0, 127]
Subnet 1 Net Address:[10, 2, 0, 128] to [10, 2, 0, 255]
Subnet 2 Net Address:[10, 2, 1, 0] to [10, 2, 1, 127]
Subnet 3 Net Address:[10, 2, 1, 128] to [10, 2, 1, 255]
Subnet 4 Net Address:[10, 2, 2, 0] to [10, 2, 2, 127]
Subnet 5 Net Address:[10, 2, 2, 128] to [10, 2, 2, 255]
Subnet 6 Net Address:[10, 2, 3, 0] to [10, 2, 3, 127]
```

There are a few corner cases which I have avoided getting into for the sake of simplicity. For example, what happens if the user enters invalid IP address or if the user enters an address like : 255.255.255.0 and asks for the next 100 subnets?

Comment: Thanks, you explained it very well.

Comment: @xypher Please accept the answer if it helps you get closer. cheers!